# Flutter - FileSystemEntity can't load all files on Samsung devices

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone please I have one issue that users report to me that only on their Samsung devices no files (images and videos) were displayed after loading, but it works fine on other Android devices(other than Samsung Brand). Here is my code below and I am using `path_provider` package and `Flutter`. Please what is possibly wrong or am I missing something? Thanks.

```
class FileType {
  final bool isImage;
  final File file;
  final DateTime? dateTime;

  FileType({
    this.isImage = false,
    required this.file,
    this.dateTime,
  });
}


Future _loadLocalFiles() async {
  final Map<String, List<FileType>>? _wsfiles = {
    "images": [],
    "videos": [],
    "images_videos": []
  };
  Map<String, List<FileType>>? get wsfiles => _wsfiles!;

  _wsfiles!['images']!.clear();
  _wsfiles!['videos']!.clear();
  _wsfiles!['images_videos']!.clear();
  final status = await Permission.storage.status;
  if (status.isDenied || status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    setLoading(DirLoading.needPermission);
    return;
  }
  List<String> pathDirs = [];
  final getExDir = await getExternalStorageDirectories();
  for (var d in getExDir!) {
    const String internalPath = 'WhatsApp Business/Media/.Statuses/';
    const String rootDirectory =
        'Android/media/com.whatsapp.w4b/WhatsApp Business/Media/.Statuses/';
    final splitInternalPath = d.path.split("Android")[0] + internalPath;
    final splitRootPath = d.path.split("Android")[0] + rootDirectory;

    pathDirs.add(splitInternalPath);
    pathDirs.add(splitRootPath);
  }
  final Map<String, List<FileType>> files =
      await _getFileTypes(paths: pathDirs);
  _wsfiles!['videos']!.addAll(files['videos']!);
  _wsfiles!['images']!.addAll(files['images']!);
}


Future<Map<String, List<FileType>>> _getFileTypes({required List<String> paths}) async {
  List<FileType> mapVideoFiles = [];
  List<FileType> mapImageFiles = [];
  for (String path in paths) {
    if (await Directory(path).exists()) {
      final dirFiles = await Directory(path)
          .list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
          .toList();

      List<FileSystemEntity> videoFiles =
          dirFiles.where((f) => f.path.contains('.mp4')).toList();

      List<FileSystemEntity> imageFiles = dirFiles
          .where((element) =>
              element.path.contains('.jpg') ||
              element.path.contains('.jpeg') ||
              element.path.contains('.png'))
          .toList();

      for (FileSystemEntity fv in videoFiles) {
        if (mapVideoFiles.isEmpty) {
          mapVideoFiles.clear();
        }
        mapVideoFiles.add(
          FileType(
            file: File(fv.path),
            dateTime: (await fv.stat()).modified,
          ),
        );
      }

      for (FileSystemEntity fi in imageFiles) {
        if (mapImageFiles.isEmpty) {
          mapImageFiles.clear();
        }
        mapImageFiles.add(
          FileType(
            file: File(fi.path),
            dateTime: (await fi.stat()).modified,
            isImage: true,
          ),
        );
      }
      mapImageFiles.sort(
        (a, b) => b.dateTime!.compareTo(a.dateTime!),
      );
      mapVideoFiles.sort(
        (a, b) => b.dateTime!.compareTo(a.dateTime!),
      );
    }
  }

  return {
    "images": mapImageFiles,
    "videos": mapVideoFiles,
  };
}
```

Comment: you could replicate issue by running your app on `Samsung` device in debug mode and see if console show any exception has thrown

Comment: most likely it is caused by "magic" `d.path.split("Android")[0]` - what is it supposed to do?

Comment: You may be right. On Samsung devices, the resulting String does not contain "Android" as the delimiter.

Comment: @Ruchit, I run the app on a Samsung device, it didn't throw any errors and no media files are displayed.

Comment: @pskink, if I run print to output **d** and **d.path.split("Android")[0]** in for loop, the output should be like this
                      **Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ljsharp.whatssaver/files'**
                     **[/storage/emulated/0/, /data/com.ljsharp.whatssaver/files]**
                      **Directory: '/storage/23A3-151A/Android/data/com.ljsharp.whatssaver/files'**
                      **[/storage/23A3-151A/, /data/com.ljsharp.whatssaver/files]**

Comment: i mean that your assumption that every path you got from `getExternalStorageDirectories` method has to contain exactly one "Android" sub-path can be wrong

Comment: Okay understood @pskink. So please what should I do then?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a long workaround, I found out that in Android 11, Google introduced shared storage so we need to add two permissions like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_PERMISSION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and then request users to grant these access permission using the permission_handler package like this.

```
final status = await Permission.storage.status;
const statusManageStorage = Permission.manageExternalStorage;
    if (status.isDenied ||
        !status.isGranted ||
        !await statusManageStorage.isGranted) {
      await [
        Permission.storage,
        Permission.mediaLibrary,
        Permission.requestInstallPackages,
        Permission.manageExternalStorage,
      ].request();
}
```

Hope it will help someone in future. Thank everyone for taking the time to answer.